# 2 divs in a fullscreen header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I want to have a full screen header with 2 `div`, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyheT.jpg)

This is what I did so far, the divs are not 100% width and I need to add overlay to the right div (like the example).

```css
.masthead {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 200px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  /*background: url(../img/main_pic.jpg) no-repeat bottom center scroll;*/
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover
}

.masthead .intro-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle
}

.masthead .intro-body .brand-heading {
  font-size: 50px
}

.masthead .intro-body .intro-text {
  font-size: 18px
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masthead {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0
  }
  .masthead .intro-body .brand-heading {
    font-size: 100px
  }
  .masthead .intro-body .intro-text {
    font-size: 22px
  }
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
}

.left {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="intro-body">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto left">
          <p class="intro-text">left</p>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle js-scroll-trigger">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto right">
          <p class="intro-text">right</p>
          <form class="contact-form row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <label></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <label></label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label></label>
              <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="tel" required>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
              <label></label>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">send</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/dangur/pen/KZKgqE)

Comment: "and I need to add overlay to the right div (like the example)." I dont really understand what you mean by that. For the width problem see my answer.

Comment: Hi, your div with a "container" class has a max-width: 1140px; property, that's why the widht of your inner divs are 50% of 1140px, and not 50% of the viewport width. For the overlay, it's just a rgba background on the right div, the background-image is applied to the the header.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can achieve a full-width container by using the class `.container-fluid`
2. Add the background iamge to `.masthead`. Create an overlay effect by applying a background color to `.right` using `rgba`

[codepen](https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/dJyNaY)

```css
.masthead {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 200px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/3000x1000) no-repeat center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.masthead .intro-body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.masthead .intro-body .brand-heading {
  font-size: 50px;
}
.masthead .intro-body .intro-text {
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .masthead {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .masthead .intro-body .brand-heading {
    font-size: 100px;
  }
  .masthead .intro-body .intro-text {
    font-size: 22px;
  }
}

.right {
  background: rgba(0, 25, 84, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="intro-body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto left">
          <p class="intro-text">left</p>
          <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle js-scroll-trigger">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 mx-auto right">
          <p class="intro-text">right</p>
          <form class="contact-form row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <label></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <label></label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <label></label>
              <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="tel" required>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
              <label></label>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">send</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: @user8544 hmm, I don't see what you're seeing. Do you mean the image isn't full height?

Comment: I mean the linear-gradient should fill the header, like the example - https://imgur.com/a/3FXjj

Comment: @user8544 Oh I see, I misunderstood. You just need to add the style to the header instead of `.right`. I'll update answer

Comment: Thanks again but I think you misunderstood me again. Like in the example - https://imgur.com/a/3FXjj there are 2 columns inside the header, I want the gradient to only be on the right div just like the example. See the gradient 
 here https://imgur.com/a/Oion4 vs here https://imgur.com/a/3FXjj

Comment: OK, so you want the background image to span both columns, but the overlay should only be on the right?

Comment: Perfect, thank you and sorry I didn't explain myself well.

Comment: No problem, my fault - it's morning here :/

Answer (score 0):

Both of your div's are 50% width (defined by `col-lg-6`) of its container.
The reason your container isnt fullscreen, is the fact your'e using the `container` class which generates a fixed width container for the bigger viewports and only gets fluid on the XS viewport.

If you need a "always 100%" container you can just use `container-fluid` instead of `container`.